# PHP loop the INSERT MySQL for each result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, web-scraping, foreach

I have already a script which scrapes all the urls of one csv with simple HTML dom.

The output is like this:

```
CoolerMaster Devastator II Azul
```

---

```
Coolbox DeepTeam - Combo teclado, ratón y alfombrilla
```

---

```
Asus Claymore RED - Teclado gaming
```

---

```
INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('Asus Claymore RED - Teclado gaming')

Items added to the database!

INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('Asus Claymore RED - Teclado gaming')

Items added to the database!

INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('Asus Claymore RED - Teclado gaming')

Items added to the database!
```

As you can see, the scrape contains 3 different products, but when I try to insert to the MySQL database, it only saves the last product --- but three times.

Here you can see my PHP Code for that:

```
<?php

require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);

function scrapUrl($url) 
{
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    global $name;
    $names = $html->find('h1');
    foreach ($names as $name) {
       echo $name->innertext;
       echo '<br>';
    }

    $rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));
    foreach ($csv as $linea) {
        $url = $linea[0];
        scrapUrl($url);
    }
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    foreach ($csv as $linea) {
        $url = $linea[0];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('$name->plaintext')";
        print ("<p> $sql </p>");    
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Items added to the database!";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    ?>
```

So, what I need is the MySQL query add:

```
INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('CoolerMaster Devastator II Azul')

Items added to the database!

INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('Coolbox DeepTeam - Combo teclado, ratón y alfombrilla')

Items added to the database!

INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('Asus Claymore RED - Teclado gaming')

Items added to the database!
```

Comment: Why not use a single `INSERT` statement?

Comment: hello @TimBiegeleisen, sorry but i don't understand what do you mean... Can you explain me a little more? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using "$name->plaintext" in your INSERT statement, when this variable "$name" is not even getting set inside your cycle?

Comment: @MihanEntalpo because what i wan't to add to my MySQL table is all the names of the products. (each one in one MySQL table row)

Comment: why are you looping 2x over the csv, why not combine that.

Comment: You have to set $name variable to a current item, that was read from the csv file. But you are looping through $csv variable, placing its items into $linea variable, then, putting it into a url variable, and where is a "name" value here? Nowhere!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix how can i combine that ?

Comment: @MihanEntalpo i know it's a newbie error, can you help me ? thanks!

Comment: @A.Sanchez - this code actually runs all the way through?  I find that hard to believe as you have infinite recursion.  I will show you in my answer in a minute.

Comment: Yes, as i have already explain, the code works and scrape all the names of the URLS wich i have in my CSV.

BUT the problem is in the MySQL Query, it only saves the last item, but as many products we have (or urls in the csv, as you wan't.)

I need it saves all the scraped data ($name) in this case, to MySQL rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after been thinking about this for quite some time, I've managed to make it work.

I leave the code in case someone else can use it.

```
    <?php


    require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);


    function scrapUrl($url) 
    {

        $html = new simple_html_dom();

        $html->load_file($url);

        global $name;
        global $price;
        global $manufacturer;


        $result = array();
        foreach($html->find('h1') as $name){
        $result[] = $name->plaintext;
            echo $name->plaintext;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        foreach($html->find('h2') as $manufacturer){
        $result[] = $manufacturer->plaintext;
            echo $manufacturer->plaintext;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        foreach($html->find('.our_price_display') as $price){
        $result[] = $price->plaintext;
            echo $price->plaintext;
            echo '<br>';
        }

        $servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

        // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

        $price_go=str_replace(",",".",str_replace(" €","",$price->plaintext));


$sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre, nombreFabricante, precio) VALUES('$name->plaintext', '$manufacturer->plaintext', $price_go)";


print ("<p> $sql </p>");

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Producto añadido al comparador!";
    echo '<br>';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
        //echo $url;

    }

    $rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));

    //print_r($csv); // Verás que es un array donde cada elemento es array con una de las url.





foreach ($csv as $linea) {
    $url = $linea[0];
    scrapUrl($url);
}


    ?>
```

I'm pretty sure i have some trash in my code, but it works.

I hope it help for someone.

Regards and thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, just formatted:  ( please check it you have a missing `}` )

```
function scrapUrl($url) 
{
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    global $name;  // -- using global is crap - I would avoid that.  Pass the object in as an argument of the function eg.  scrapUrl($url, $name) 
    $names = $html->find('h1');
    foreach ($names as $name) {
         // -- your re-assigning $name overwriting you global on each iteration of this loop 
        // -- What is the purpose of this? it does nothing but output?
        echo $name->innertext;
        echo '<br>';
    }
// -- missing }  where is this function closed at?

    $rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));

    foreach ($csv as $linea) {
        // -- this can be combined with the one with the query
        // -- just put the function call in that one and delete this one
        $url = $linea[0];
        scrapUrl($url); //recursive? depends where you function is closed
        // -- whats the purpose of this function, it returns nothing?
    }

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    foreach ($csv as $linea) {
        $url = $linea[0]; // -- whats this url used for?
        $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('$name->plaintext')";
         // -- query is vulnerable to SQL injection? prepared statement
         // -- whats $name->plaintext? where is it assigned at?
        print ("<p> $sql </p>");    
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Items added to the database!";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
       // -- when you loop over the CSV but insert $name->plaintext multiple times
       // -- where is that property changed inside this loop, how is it correlated to the csv data
    }

    $conn->close();
```

So first off you are missing a closing `}` Depending where that should be, depends on what else you have wrong.

One of you loops for the CSV can be eliminated ( maybe ), anyway I put bunch of notes in with comments like this `// --`

Your main issue, or the reason you inserts are the same is these lines

```
foreach ($csv as $linea) {
    $url = $linea[0]; // -- whats this url used for?
    $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre) VALUES('$name->plaintext')";
    // -- $name->plaintext does not change per iteration of the loop
    // -- you are just repeatedly inserting that data
   ...
```

See you insert the value of `$name->plaintext` but this has no correlation to the `$csv` variable and you are not modifying it.  It's no surprise it stays the same.

Ok, now that I picked apart your code ( nothing personal ). Let's see if we can simplify it a bit.

**UPDATE**  This is the best I can do given the above code.  I just combined it, fixed some logical errors, trimmed it down and simplified it.  It's a common mistake of beginners to over-complicate the task. ( but there is no way for me to test this )

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));

//prepare query outside of the loops
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO productos (nombre)VALUES(?)");

foreach ($csv as $linea) {

    //iterate over each csv line
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    //load url $linea[0]
    $html->load_file($linea[0]); 

    //find names in the document, and return them
    foreach( $html->find('h1') as $name ){
        //iterate over each name and bind elements text to the query
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $name->plaintext);

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            echo "Items added to the database!";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
}
```

There I further simplified it as it doesn't really make sense to have the function `scrapUrl()`.  We're not re-using that code, so it adds a function call and makes the code harder to read by having it.

Even if it doesn't work strait away, I encourage you to compare the original code to what I have.  And sort of walk through it in your mind, so you can get an feel for how I removed some of those redundancies etc.

For reference

- mysqli prepare: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- mysqli bind_param: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
- mysqli execute: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: I have the same output and the same INSERT in the MySQL. Only the last product name scrapped is added in my MySQL table.

:(

The purpose of the echo $name->innertext; it's only to see the output and know where i am.

Comment: @A.Sanchez - this is because you never change `$name->plaintext` in the last loop as you insert it to the DB.

Comment: Wow... yes... I'm sorry i'm very newbie with PHP and it's my first project.

I have really no idea how to do that works :(

Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @A.Sanchez - see my update.  I have no way to test this as I don't have the CSV, or the DB schema.  Even if I did have those, I'm probably to lazy this morning to do it.

Comment: Thank you @ArtisticPhoenix , i will try with your example. And i will try to do it. 

I let you know! Best regards

Comment: Sure, don't let it overwhelm you, I have 6 years PHP experience and I write a few thousand lines of code a day, so for me it's pretty easy to pick it apart.

Comment: "Scrap" != "Scrape"

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of problems in your code.

1. First, you have function scrapUrl, that takes $url as an argument, but doesn't output anyhting. It's setting global $name variable, but, although it's find several names, it putting only the last one to the $name variable, because it's walking through a series of $names, put it's text into $name, and go for the next one, so, only last item is stored to your $name variable.

I would recommend, that your change your scrapUrl function, so it store names of scrapped products into an array, and return that array.

2. Second, I'm cannot understand how do you put your data into a csv file, the code, you've privided looks like it shouldn't work properly. Are you sure, that you are writing the right data in a csv file? Maybe here you are just reading data from file - in that case, I'm sorry.
3. The third: you are reading data from csv, and when moving line by line in the cycle, but the data is going nowhere. To my opinion, you should but $linea[0] into your SQL query, but you are putting $name->plaintext where, when $name is set only once in your scrapUrl, as I've mentioned above.

I would recommend, that you use the right variable in your SQL-query to pass data to it.

Also, it's better to use PDO and prepared statements instead of inserting raw data in your string-literals SQL queries.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.

1- Yes, i think that is the problem.. How can i store the names of scrapped products into an array, and return that array in my MySQL query?

2- I don't need to write anything on the csv, the csv is only for read the URL's to scrape

3- $linea[0] is only each row on my csv file, right? (So, it's the URLS, and i don't need them in my MySQL table.) I only need the correct names in my mysql table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. In your  foreach ($names as $name) cycle, write something like result_array[] = $name->plain_text. So, at the end of the function you'll get filled result_array, that you can return to the outer scope.

2 and 3. Ok, I though, that you saving gathered names into a csv. So, as you don't need to save names into csv, you should in your last cycle run scrapUrl for your linea[0], and walk through returned names (scrapUrl should return it, remember?), inserting them with INSERT query. Try it.

Comment: when i add result_array[] = $name->plain_text to my foreach $names as $name

i have this error: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: Didn't you forget $ sign before result_array ?